# cannot read html page in facebook api

Tags: php, html, facebook, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to read a website html output in facebook messenger api, the code is working on the server, but it gives errors when I try it in facebook api (messenger), This is what I get:

```
    Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead.
```

I've tried file_get_contents, fopen,readfile, curl and all brought up the same error.
I've tried to change the website to a secure connection (https) when using curl, to https://google.com, and the error message changed to:

```
    <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
    <H1>302 Moved</H1>
    The document has moved
    <A HREF="https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=SaHbWPOrQXp_JvNB">here</A>.
    </BODY></HTML>
```

And stackoverflow shows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Forbidden</h1>
    <p>You don't have permission to access /
    on this server.<br />
    </p>
    <p>Additionally, a 403 Forbidden
    error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
    </body></html>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Google can not be used in iframe and curl the google server blocks it , your code would work just fine in other sites, only way is to build owm page and use [google search api.](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

code example:

Making HTTP Requests Directly

If Google Authentication is desired for external applications, or a Google API is not available yet in this library, HTTP requests can be made directly.

The authorize method returns an authorized Guzzle Client, so any request made using the client will contain the corresponding authorization.

```
// create the Google client
$client = new Google_Client();

/**
 * Set your method for authentication. Depending on the API, This could be
 * directly with an access token, API key, or (recommended) using
 * Application Default Credentials.
 */
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_ME);

// returns a Guzzle HTTP Client
$httpClient = $client->authorize();

// make an HTTP request
$response = $httpClient->get('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me');
```